# How do I get Google to crawl my content when it's only displayed when you fill in a form?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, googlebot, google-index

I have a webpage. **It has a form and the "results" section is blank**. When **the user searches for items**, and a list that pops up, he/she chooses one option from list and then the **corresponding results are displayed in results section.**

I once decided to log every ip,url of person with time that visits my page.
One ip was 66.249.73.26, and on doing google search I came to know it is ip 
of google bot.

[link for whatmyipaddress google bot](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/66.249.73.26)

Now when I searched for the links that this ip visited, it was like this:

```
search?id=100
search?id=110
...
search?id=200
...
```

then afterwards it incremented in steps of 1, like 400,401..

But **people search for strings and not numbers**. And because googlebot searches for numbers like this, I think the corresponding content is never displayed and so
**my page content is never indexed, even though it has rich content.**

So I want to ask you is that **in order to show google bot all the content that the webpage has, should I list all the results in index page and ask users to enter string to filter results?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a [site map](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) that describes all the content of your website.

Comment: I tried to use automated site map generator, but it searches for links in same way, like search?id=1,2,3,4,5...so on. Should I create site map manually?

Comment: google bot and other bots can try whatever they want. You need to run over you db and generate all possible urls.

Comment: all possible urls? Meaning all possible keywords? Like for keyword "jaguar", we have "j","ja","jag"..like this?Is there is a limit to all possible urls?

Comment: there is a limit of 50,000 urls or 10 MB per sitemap, but you can have as many sitemaps as you want. Also register to Google Webmaster Tools, there you can tell google about your sitemaps and other usefull tools